# PHP merge arrays if they have the same key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

I have an array of associative arrays.

```
$array = [
    ['report_date' => 'date', 'name' => 'name'], 
    ['report_date' => 'date', 'color' => 'color']
];
```

I want to sort through this array and if

```
$array[x]['report_date'] === $array[y]['report_date']
```

then I need to perform a merge that would return in this case:

```
$newArray = [['report_date'=>date,'name'=>name,'color'=>color]]
```

Of course we would need to take into account that there may be multiple arrays that fulfill this requirement and we would have to merge them as well.

I've tried a couple of things, that resulted in mapping and foreach merges that took forever to process and in the end couldn't get it working.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"I've tried a couple of things, "_ - Please share what you've tried, together with some real examples of the original input and the expected output.

Comment: My initial advice would be to rethink what you're trying to accomplish. When your solution looks like this, it usually means you either don't totally understand the problem or you wandered down a rabbit hole. Perhaps this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: I was in the process of editing my question, but someone answered it with the desired outcome. I will definitely upvote your guys' comments since both are sound pieces of advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new array, indexed by `report_date` and push the values into it:

```
$out=[];
foreach($array as $subarray){
    foreach($subarray as $key=>$val){
        $out[$subarray['report_date']][$key]=$val;
    }
}

var_dump($out);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed as the solution. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you.